# what is a possible work around for get_results in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on displaying the user database as a table in wordpress. Using get_results() i am getting my desired output also. But is there any workaround for this by passing arguments. Here is my work :

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<?php

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix .'users';
$row = $wpdb->get_results("select*from $table_name");

echo "<h2><center><u>List Of Members</u></center></h2>";
echo "<table class='table'>";
echo "<thead> 
      <tr>


      <th><center>Member Name</center></th>
      <th><center>Age</center></th>
      <th><center>Class</center></th>
      <th><center>Address</center></th>
      </tr>
      <thead>";

foreach ($row as $row) 

    {

    $usid = $row->ID;
    $username = $row->user_login;

    echo "<tr><td>".$username."</td>";
    $age=get_user_meta( $usid, 'age', true);
    echo "<td>".$age."</td>";
    $class=get_user_meta($usid, 'class', true);
    echo "<td>".$class."</td>";
    $address=get_user_meta($usid, 'address', true);
    echo "<td>".$address."</td>";
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. use get_users this article will help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Comment: <?php

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix .'users';
$args=array('ID' => $usid ,
   'user_login' => $username,
   'meta_key' => 'address',
   'meta_value' => $address);

$row = $wpdb->get_users( $args );

foreach ($row as $row)



now an error is happening undefined method get_users()

Comment: get_users need to run without $wpdb;